# jexcel table SUM column after change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to sum a column in jexcel after entering a value

This code is not working I don't know why:

```
var change = function(instance, cell, value) {
var cellName = $(instance).jexcel('getColumnNameFromId',$(cell).prop('id'));

$('#log').append('New change on cell'+ cellName+'to:'+ value + '<br>');

var thisid = $(cell).prop('id');
var splitted = thisid.split("-");
var nextcellid = ++splitted[1];
var nextcell = '0-'+nextcellid;
console.log(nextcell,'nextcell');
$("td#"+nextcell).html('<span>total</span>');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `onafterchange` event:

`$('#my').jexcel({
    data:data,
    colHeaders: ['Model'],
    colWidths: [ 300 ],
    onafterchange:function(instance){
      console.log(instance)
    },
    columns: [
        { type: 'text' },
    ]
});`

full handing events ready this url
https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/docs/events

or using this example

https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/examples/including-formulas-on-your-spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, you can just use =SUM(A1:A10) in the column you would like to have the total. Pretty much like excel.